# ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE produces error

Tags: java, sql-server

I am working on a Java project with sql server database and once I use

```
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

I get error message "The cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported" .

Anyone has got any clue why this is happening ? Everything was working fine until I used this code...

Comment: your answer is simple, under your nose, your secret SQL Engine doesn't suporting `SCROLL_INSENSITIVE / CONCUR_UPDATABLE` == `The cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported`,

Comment: Maybe it is some configuration problem, I mean, it's MSFT SQL SERVER 2008. On another project with the same line I did not have any problem !

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using?  I use jTDS with Microsoft SQL Server and [its website](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/resultSets.html) states that `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` "only works with read-only concurrency".

Comment: I am using the driver provided by Microsoft. I will look into jTDS driver as I never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                      ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```